# Сколько раз за время выполнения фрагмента происходило изменение ячейки S

Tags: алгоритм

Помогите составить s=f(n) функцию которая отражает, cколько раз за время выполнения фрагмента происходило изменение ячейки S. Сколько не пытаюсь, получаю одну и ту же не правильную функцию.

[[image: Алгоритм[1]]
[image: Неудачные попытки]

Comment: Помогите понять, что вам нужно? Написать вычисление функции 6n^2+n+1? или что?

Comment: Помогите составить функцию либо укажите мне на ошибки (6n^2 + n + 1 не есть искомая функция)

Comment: А какая искомая? 2n^3+1?

Comment: Нет, не подходит

Comment: Вам нужно написать функцию зависимости s от n?

Comment: Да, все верно..

Comment: 2n3 +n2 + 1? А так?

Comment: Тоже не то, только при n=5 правильно отработала

Comment: Ячейка стала функцией? Кажется условие в вопросе не соответствует тому что в коментах.

Comment: Попробуй `1 + 4n^2 + (5n + 4n^3) / 3`

Comment: @Suvitruf Чёт не понял, зачем *требует правки* пометили? Вроде ж все нормально описано. У человека не получается вывести закономерность количества повторений цикла (код там есть) от входных данных (n). Приводит его решение (неверное) и просит помочь разобраться.